# correct this value using find() in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
    console.log(this.tiles.find(this.findStart))
```

returns expected results using this code:

```
    findStart: function (value) {
      var x = 5, y = 10;
      return value.x === x && value.y === y
    },
```

but not this code:

```
    findStart: function (value) {
      var x = this.room.startX, y = this.room.startY;
      return value.x === x && value.y === y
    },
```

How do I pass the correct "this" value to the second set of code?

Comment: Is findStart a method of the Vue? Are tiles and room data properties of the Vue?

Comment: yes, findStart is a method. tiles and room are data properties.

Comment: So it turns out the find method isn't the problem. On mount I run a function that assigns this.room.startX = this.getRandom(0,1000); If I comment out that assignment, the find works perfectly. So is this.room.startX actually being defined as the function getRandom()? If so, why was typeOf(this.room.startX) showing as "number"?

Comment: let firstStackOverflowQuestion = "fail". 

Sorry everyone. My function to set value of this.room was setting a value to high to be found in my this.tile array. Simple fix and is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is written, your function is not *bound* to any specific context, so `this` will refer to the `window` object, which is the top-most context.

You should use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to make your function *bound* to your specific context.

```
console.log(this.titles.find(this.findStart.bind(this)));
```

Comment: That still returned undefined. Here is what it looks like in the chrome devtools console:

console.log($vm.tiles.find($vm.findStart.bind($vm)));
>undefined

Also...

$vm.tiles
>(8000) [Object,  ..., Object…]

$vm.room.startX
>610

$vm.room.startY
>453

console.log($vm.tiles.find(value => value.x == 2 && value.y == 2));
>Object… // Correct response

console.log($vm.tiles.find(value => value.x == $vm.room.startX && value.y == $vm.room.startY))
> undefined

Comment: FWIW, Vue methods are bound to the Vue instance on instantiation, so this wouldn't really do anything.

Answer (score 0):

"this" inside the function own only the code within that function so i assume you want to call the room variable but before that you have to bind "this" with the 
object that owns the room object

Comment: The top level object is a Vue instance, and then *.data.room 

new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        room: {
          number: 20,
          startX: 3,
          startY: 3
        },